# Mocking a Rails application object with mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, mocha.js

I'm writing a generator and I need to get mock a Rails.application object and get back the Rails.application.class.parent as the name of the Rails application.

```
def test_model_with_application_namespace
  name = "Dummyapp"
  application = Rails.stubs(:application).class.parent.returns(name)
  run_generator ["file", "--namespaced"]
  assert_file "app/models/myapp/file.rb", /class Dummyapp::File < ActiveRecord::Base/
end
```

This is what I have so far for my test.

Comment: Giving your code is helpful, but it would be even more helpful to let us know what was failing and what errors your getting. Reading this, I'm assuming that your `Rails.stubs(:application)` line isn't working. But I'm not sure if that is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the object retured by `Rails.application.class` to be a mock that responds to `parent` and returns `name`. Right now, you just stub out application. You need parent, class, and application to be mocks. There is probably a cleaner way of doing it, but I think this will do what you want:

```
 application = Rails.stubs(:application).returns(mock(:class => mock(:parent => name)))
```